# React Native : Expo Start Gives EIO: i/o error, read

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, expo

I created a new Expo project using `expo init Myprojectname`. When I try to run `expo start` it throws an error: I tried running the project from my Snack Expo. It threw the same error for snack too.

`expo start`

```
Starting project at C:\Users\Nitish\Desktop\nitschool

EIO: i/o error, read

Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.
```

The result of running `expo diagnostics`:

```
Expo CLI 3.18.5 environment info:

** System:**

** OS: Windows 8.1 6.3.9600**

** Binaries:**

** Node: 12.16.2 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE**

** npm: 6.14.4 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD**

** IDEs:**

** Android Studio: Version 3.6.0.0 AI-192.7142.36.36.6392135**

** npmPackages:**

** expo: ^37.0.0 => 37.0.7**

** react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0**

** react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.0.tar.gz => 0.61.4**

** react-navigation: latest => 4.3.7**
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run expo upgrade in the project folder and then expo start -c